# onesignal notificationExtenderService VerifyError: Verifier rejected

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I have added NotificationExtenderService for OneSignal.

It was working perfectly last week (when checked it the last time), but now it is giving me the following error on receiving the notification. However, when I am not extending the NotificationExtenderService then I am able to receive the notification.

I need custom notification handling thus want to extend with NotificationExtenderService.

Error Log on receiving the OneSignal notification:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.goambee.theproject, PID: 17935
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.packagename.NotificationExtenderOneSignal due to bad method java.lang.Object packagename.NotificationExtenderOneSignal.access$super(com.packagename.NotificationExtenderOneSignal, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) (declaration of 'com.packagename.NotificationExtenderOneSignal' appears in /data/app/com.projectname-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3639)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:218)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1801)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```